# Pattern match in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
select Document_id 
from Document_Master 
where Document_id like 'APJ1.000753%'
```

result displaying like that

```
APJ1.000753_DIS001.PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_DIS001.PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001(1).PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001(2).PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001.PDF

APJ1.000753_OTH001.PDF
```

but i want based upon underscore count, result should be

```
APJ1.000753_DIS001.PDF

APJ1.000753_OTH001.PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_DIS001.PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001(1).PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001(2).PDF

APJ1.000753_IP753_OTH001.PDF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Document_id
from Document_Master
where Document_id like 'APJ1.000753%'
order by len(Document_id) - len(replace(Document_id, '_', '')), Document_id
```